# schema extraction/identification/recognition using Python

Tags: python, schema

Is there a module/package/strategy for identifying the schema/attribute list when we provide a list of json files.

Pseudo code:

1. Provide source file/files
2. Each file can have one or more json objects
3. Identify the attributes in the json object

Example:

```
[
    {
        "id": "id1",
        "name": "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "id": "id2",
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "age": 30
    }
]
```

Output:

```
["id","name","age"]
```

Do we have a python module(preferably) that does this?

Comment: smth like https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema ?

Answer (score 0):

There's the python 3 json module from the standard library.

```
import json

with open("my_file.json",'r') as file:
  objs = json.loads(file.read())
```

Objs would be an array if your json had an array. Objects are decoded to dictionaries.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html for details.